# Миграция данных пользователя в предзагруженую базу данных Core Data при обновлении приложения

Tags: objective-c, coredata, миграция

У приложения есть предустановленная база данных в Core Data. Пользователь добавляет данные в туже базу. К данным пользователя присваивается свой индекс, для фильтрации их от предустановленных данных. 
Как, при обновлении приложения, перенести данные пользователя в обнавленную предустановленную базу?

Процессы предустановки и миграций данных в core data ясны. Не понятно как совместить два этих процесса при обновлении приложения.

Comment: Пришел к решению, что нужно разделить хранилище на два хранилища (хранилище приложение и пользователя). Splitting Data Across Multiple Persistent Stores. И при обновлении приложения обновлять хранилище приложения, а пользовательское не трогать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При первом запуске обновленного приложения сделать миграцию.